# word cloud for expressions more than one word

Tags: python

I have an excel file with a column containing some string values. some of these values are more than one word. for example I have a cell with the value "Mental health". but when I create the word cloud it divides it into two words. what should I do if I want to have each column as one observation?

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\.......\jj.csv", encoding='utf8')
df = df["Outcome"]
our_mask = np.array(Image.open("C:\\Users\\.....\\baby.png"))

stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)

wc = WordCloud(background_color = "white", font_path='arial',
               colormap='Reds', random_state=1,repeat=True,
               collocations=False,
               max_words = 150,
               stopwords = stopwords,
               mask = our_mask,
               contour_width = 1,
               contour_color = 'Gray').generate(str(df))

#Plotting
plt.imshow(wc, interpolation = 'bilinear')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem first I used the value_counts() function to get the frequency of my "Name" values.
then i changed my code as follows...

```
d = dict(zip(df["Name"], df["frequencies"]))
wc = WordCloud(background_color = "white", font_path='arial',
               colormap='prism', random_state=1,repeat=True,
               collocations=False,
               max_words = 2000,
               stopwords = stopwords,
               mask = our_mask,
               contour_width = 1,
               contour_color = 'red', width=1600, height=800).generate_from_frequencies(d)
```